# PyCharm cannot find references when importing classes from unyt package

Tags: python, pycharm, units-of-measurement, yt-project

I am trying to work with yt Project's `unyt`, a Python package "for working with data that has physical units" ([source](https://unyt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)).

When I try to import units using syntax like `from unyt import degC`, PyCharm tells me `Cannot find reference 'degC'`.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have verified that `unyt==2.7.1` is in my PyCharm interpreter.

[image: unyt in interpreter]

---

**What I See**

[image: Cannot find reference]

Sample Code (to prove the code works at runtime)

```py
from unyt import degC  # Source: https://github.com/yt-project/unyt/issues/99#issue-477869520


t1 = 0 * degC
t1.convert_to_base()
print(t1)
```

Output: `273.15 K`

---

**Related Questions**

Since the `degC` class is added to the `unyt` namespace at runtime, the deeper question is this: [PyCharm: how to infer types of objects created at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60383370/11163122)

---

**Versions**

- Python: `3.7`
- unyt: `2.7.1`
- PyCharm: `2019.2.5 CE`

Comment: Feel free to open an issue about this on GitHub. Does PyCharm have a way to discover attributes that get created at runtime like this?

Comment: Hi @ngoldbaum thank you for reaching out (btw `unyt` is awesome)!  The reason I posted here was I thought it was more a PyCharm problem than a `unyt` problem.  That the `degC` is created at runtime probably has something to do with things, I will look into that.  If nothing comes of this question, I will make a GitHub issue in the `unyt` repo!

Comment: You may have a better time getting an answer from PyCharm experts if you ask a question that doesn’t depend on installing anything.

Comment: You could navigate to the mentioned `__init__.py` by right clicking on `unyt` in `from unyt import degC` and choosing `Go To - Go To Declaration` and see that there is no explicit definition of `degC` :( That is why PyCharm highlights it.

Comment: I went ahead and made this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60383370/11163122, which gets at the true problem.