# PyCharm: how to infer types of objects created at runtime

Tags: python, pycharm, runtime, type-hinting

I am trying to use a library that creates objects, and adds them to the global namespace at runtime.

PyCharm cannot find the references to the objects, because they aren't originally in the namespace.

How can I get PyCharm introspection to not complain "Cannot find reference..."?  I don't want to use `noinspection` tags.

---

**Sample Code**

To help make my question clear, I have drawn up sample code of using an object created at runtime in PyCharm.

`main.py`

```py
from some_import import some_obj_1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"obj_1.some_attr = {some_obj_1.some_attr}")
```

`some_import.py`

```py
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, attr_init: int = 0):
        self.some_attr = attr_init


globals()["some_obj_1"] = SomeClass(1)
```

Output of running `main.py`:

```py
obj_1.some_attr = 1
```

What I see in PyCharm:

[image: main.py view]

---

**Relevant Articles**

[Dynamic runtime type inference in PyCharm 2.7](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/02/dynamic-runtime-type-inference-in-pycharm-2-7/)

This article suggests enabling `Collect run-time types information for code insight`.  However, enabling this settings and running the debugger did not solve my problem.

---

**Possible Solutions**

- Making a PyCharm stub file
- Suppressing the error message using PyCharm `noinspection` tag + a type hint

  - This is "manual", and thus I don't like this solution very much

```py
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
from some_import import some_obj_1, SomeClass

some_obj_1: SomeClass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"obj_1.some_attr = {some_obj_1.some_attr}")
```

---

This was made using `Python 3.7.6` and `PyCharm 2019.2.5 CE`.

Comment: There is no way for pycharm to determine such things without running your code. You can either write a stub file, use hardcoded declarations like in your example or write a pycharm plugin that allows you to pass your information to pycharm. For example you could write a pycharm plugin that parses lines that mutate `globals()`

Comment: Thank you @kmaork for confirming my readings/intuition!

Comment: Of course, not a solution, but if you know the name of the object that you want to create (like in the example), that is, if the name of the object is not in a variable (like in `globals()[varname] = ...`), then without touching the `main.py`, you can always add the type hint line right after the dynamic creation of the variable in `some_import.py`.

Comment: Good thinking @JCGonzalez!  I tested that, and it's a viable solution :). It only works if one can make changes to `some_import.py`.  Unfortunately, in my case `some_import.py` is inside a 3rd party pip installable package.

Comment: Oops, bad luck...  Anyway, as I said it's not a complete solution.  Hopefully, somebody will come with a plugin like the one @kmaork pointed at...

Answer (score -1):

The below link makes me think it is possible just by using the module name.

[Behaviour of global variables in "run with Python console"](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000342180-Behaviour-of-global-variables-in-run-with-Python-console-)

I've written this code but it's tough for me to test as I'm using Spyder and that works with your original attempt

```
import some_import as si


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"obj_1.some_attr = {si.some_obj_1.some_attr}")
```

Comment: Hello @Alistair!  Thank you for taking a shot.  However, this does not work.  All it does is move the `Cannot find reference` warning from the import line to be inside the `__main__` code block.